# What tool can decompile a DLL into C++ source code?

Tags: c++, dll, decompiling

I have an old DLL that stopped working (log2vis.dll) and I want to look inside it to see what objects it uses.
The DLL was written in C++ (not .NET). Is there a tool that will decompile/disassemble C++ files?

Answer (score 38):

This might be impossible or at least very hard. The DLL's contents don't depend (a lot) on it being written in C++; it's all machine code. That code might have been optimized so a lot of information that was present in the original source code is simply gone.

That said, [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/reversedisasm.aspx) is one article that goes through a lot of material about doing this.

Comment: The article is still relevant to this day but I'd suggest https://cutter.re/ as a modern tool to reverse engineer C++ binaries.

Answer (score 14):

[Hex-Rays decompiler is probably the best in this field !!!](http://www.hex-rays.com/decompiler.shtml)

Comment: This is not a good product. It generates a lot of errors.

Comment: user2587965 You are wrong.  This is indeed the best in the field but you have to get the A.I. cloud version that lets you codegen.  It generates code about as good as possible.  You obviously don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 9):

I think a C++ DLL is a machine code file. Therefore decompiling will only result in assembler code. If you can read that and create C++ from that you're good to go.

Comment: isn't there already something that can somewhat map that machine code file roughly to c or c++?

Answer (score 5):

There are no decompilers which I know about.
[W32dasm](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/WDASM-Download-1821.html) is good Win32 disassembler.

Answer (score 4):

There really isn't any way of doing this as most of the useful information is discarded in the compilation process. However, you may want to take a look at [this 
site](http://www.program-transformation.org/Transform/DeCompilation) to see if you can find some way of extracting something from the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you will *ever* get to doing such thing is a **dissasembler**, or debug info (Log2Vis.pdb).