# Compile ExcelDNAUnpack

Tags: excel, windows, visual-studio, excel-dna, xll

I've learned Excel VBA programming in the last few months and I can say that I'm now proficient at it.  However, recently I was given an add-in with a .xll extension.  I currently know little about producing `.dll`/`.xll` files; but I'm going to learn.

I found this thread [Possible to view source code or decompile XLL Excel add in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31143490/possible-to-view-source-code-or-decompile-xll-excel-add-in), which points me to [github](https://github.com/augustoproiete/ExcelDnaUnpack) to get some source code.

The `README.md` tells me how to call the command `ExcelDnaUnpack.exe`.  However, this command is not in the package. I guess I'm expected to compile the source code and produce it.

How should I do this?

Comment: For ExcelDNAUnpack, I think you are meant to download the whole solution and build it into the .exe. Then, it is usable via commandline

Comment: I'm not familiar with Windows .exe building.  Do I use Visual Studio?  I need some tips to tell me what to do initially.

Comment: Yes, you would need Visual Studio. Download, and extract, all the files/folders from the git project. Open the .sln file ins VS. In VS, you can build the solution from the “Build” menu.

Comment: @Mikey @ArcherBird You can download the `ExcelDnaUnpack.exe` from the [Releases](https://github.com/augustoproiete/ExcelDnaUnpack/releases) tab of the GitHub repository

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to compile the ExcelDnaUnpack project in order to use it. You can download the compiled version (`ExcelDnaUnpack.exe`) in the **[Releases](https://github.com/augustoproiete/ExcelDnaUnpack/releases)** tab of the repository.

[image: ExcelDnaUnpack Release Download]

There you'll find a file called `ExcelDnaUnpack.{version}.zip` which contains the `ExcelDnaUnpack.exe`. Extract the .zip file on your machine and run it.

---

If did want to build it from source, (as of this writing) all you need is Visual Studio 2017 or 2019, with .NET Framework 4.0 or higher installed.